# Theme custom color

Tags: sharepoint-designer, theme

I have been searching in my SharePoint 2007 site, but all I see it's the already made themes, since our company have their unique color and they want me to put their color to represent their company.

So any suggestion?

[image: Sahrepoint none custom!]

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the themes that is available out of the box. To change

1. Select Site Settings under Site Actions
2. Click on Site Theme under Look and Feel
3. On the Site Theme page, you can select different themes and you’ll see a preview of that theme on the left. Once you have decided on a theme, click the Apply button.

**To create your own theme**

Step 1 – Copy existing theme

1. Choose a theme to re-purpose (something that closely resembles your desired look)
2. Choose a name for your new theme
3. Copy the chosen theme in the themes folder in 12 Hive
   "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\THEMES"
4. Paste this folder and rename it to your chosen new name

Step 2 – Edit Setup Information File

1. In your new theme folder, rename OLDNAME.INF file to NEWNAME.INF (Wheat to LewTek)
   – Ensure its upper case
2. Open NEWNAME.INF with notepad or your favorite text editor (LEWTEK.INF)
3. Change the value of title under [info] from Oldname to Newname.
4. Change all values under [titles] from Oldname to Newname.

Step 3 – Edit SPTHEMES.XML

Next we need to edit this file so that we can actually choose our newly created theme. This will make it available in the list of themes on the Site Theme page.

For more information - http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointcomic/archive/2008/06/12/create-a-custom-theme-for-wss-3-0-or-moss-2007.aspx